# How to execute a Bash command from variable with argument

Tags: linux, bash

In Linux Bash, we can use `()` to execute a simple command from a variable, and take arguments. For example:

```
greet="echo hello $1"
($greet world)

hello world
```

But if we introduce another control statement, like

```
greet="if [ 1 == 1 ]; then echo hello $1; fi"
($greet world)

bash: if: command not found
```

if the variable contains `if`, `for` or other statements, get `command not found`

We can use `eval`, but can't take an argument:

```
eval $greet

hello

eval $greet world

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `world'
```

How can I execute `greet` with an argument? I hope it works with the following:

```
greet="if [ 1 == 1 ]; then echo hello $1; fi"
($greet world)

hello world
```

Comment: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: Do you want `$1` to be established at assignment time, or at expansion time? Right now, your examples all expand `$1` when the variable is assigned, not when the code is executed.

Comment: BTW, the information that you can't use a function (as given in a comment on an answer) is critical -- I think if you edited that into the question, it would make this answer distinguishable, and thus potentially ready for reopening (or at least would mean a different/better duplicate would need to be found).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing a whole command line in a variable is not safe and will have many issues.

Use functions instead:

```
greet() { if [ 1 == 1 ]; then echo hello $1; fi; }
```

Then call it as:

```
greet world
```

Which will output:

```
hello world
```

---

**(As per comments below)**

With the known risks of `eval`, you can do something like this:

```
greet='if [ 1 == 1 ]; then echo hello $1; fi'
(set -- word && eval "$greet")
```

This will output:

```
hello world
```

Comment: @Yanbin: Did this work for you?

Comment: I can't use function. The real scenario is I only can define environment variables for Jenkins group, then call one defined variable as shell script.

Comment: ok check my updated answer.

Comment: Even though `eval` is _evil`, but I like you solution. Thanks.

Comment: *"hello word"*? Not *"hello world"*?

Answer (score 1):

`if` is not a command; it is a keyword. You cannot store it in a string variable unless you use `eval`. This is because keyword parsing happens before variable expansion.

However, you can still solve the problem like [anubhava shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31925330/171318).

Comment: With `eval`, how can I pass an argument?

Comment: Passing arguments to a string parsed by `eval` isn't possible. However, when you are at the point where you are about to use `eval` you should think about a different solution. `eval` is *evil*. That's still true.